# Blazor Report Designer Generator

Tags: reporting

Can you please tell me the name of a good and useful report designer/generator free or paid for Blazor.
I used a lot of time Visual Foxpro and it's report generator and I need something like that...
Thank You Very Much !

Answer (score 1):

You can try Bold Reports’s Blazor Report Designer https://www.boldreports.com/embedded-reporting/blazor-report-designer
This is a paid tool ([Free Community](https://www.boldreports.com/community-license) edition also available) that allows you to design and generate SSRS RDL/RDLC reports using a visual interface. It offers a wide range of features, including support for various data sources, rich formatting options, and the ability to export reports to multiple formats.

Support: https://www.boldreports.com/support

Demos: https://demos.boldreports.com/home/blazor.html

Solutions: https://solutions.boldreports.com